Why I have duplicate processes in my Debian?
I can't understand, why I have duplicate processes?
2 Xorg's, 4 spacefm's, 2 i3wm's, 4 geany's and so on. What does it mean?
I'm using Debian testing on VirtualBox 7.


Process are part of a tree: pstree -p, ps -ef --forest

please post text, not a picture of text
